# How do I insert a django form in twitter bootstrap modal window?

Tags: django, forms, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a django form within a twitter bootstrap modal window but with no luck. I am fairly new to javascript, bootstrap and django. So far the modal window is launching OK but the registration form is being displayed. I feel like I am missing something obvious. Any help will be appreciated

```
<div id="mReg" class="modal fade">
     <div class="modal-header">
          <h3>STEP 1: User registration</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ reg_form.as_p }}
          </form>
      </div>    
      <div class="modal-footer">         
          <a href="#" class="btn primary">Next</a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: could you add your `view` code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I insert a django form in twitter-bootstrap modal window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276100/how-do-i-insert-a-django-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window)

Comment: This question was asked first, but the linked question was better written and includes an answer.