# Creating popups with django form

Tags: django

What will be the best way of creating django form popups .I have search online but could not fine help .Please help out .

Comment: look into jquery modals  combined with django forms

Comment: what are you looking for? an `alert` when an error appears or that the form is inside a `modal`?

Comment: I want to display a profile update form in a popup .For instance when the user clicks the update profile button ,it will display a popup containing userupdate form of the user .

Answer (score 0):

There are number of options ... The easiest would be of course jQuery: 
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

```
 $( function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
 } );

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog"><p>message</p></div>
```

Comment: how can i successfully  pass the urls of the update view in to the dialog .This is my greatest challenge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276100/how-do-i-insert-a-django-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-modal-window
Does this answer your question?